# Create Site usage reporting in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create a Dashboard to display usage site activity report.

Because my organization's policy, I can't use Sharepoint Deginer.

So, how can I do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a Dashboard to display site usage, there are site usage available in sharepoint online.

You need change to modern experience to see it. Click settings-> site usage
[image]